# [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity (cakephp)

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I have some part of codes that they do some work on a xml file.

they work perfectly out of cakephp.

but when i put it in my framework it not work. "simplexml_load_file" function in my framework cant find the xml file  .but the xml file is in the same folder which the class caller is in it!

code :

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_file("certificate.xml");
```

error :

> Warning (2): simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity "certificate.xml"
>   [APP\libs\r_s_a_processor.php, line 17]

I cant set complete path like "http://www.sample.com/app/libs/certificate.xml" beacuse htaccess change the path to the 404 page.

what is the solution?
I even put the xml file in the webroot/files path! but nothing changed :(

[image]

Comment: Try to `echo gwtcwd();` just before, you'er sure that's the right directory?

Comment: thanx a lot echo getcwd() helped :).

Comment: @afsane: If you've found an answer to your question now, please leave it in form of an answer below. If you haven't you should make this visible in a comment, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo gwtcwd(); just before, you'er sure that's the right directory